# Launching app on apple watch - stuck on loading indicator

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch, watch

I have a problem with launching application on Apple Watch.
When i try to run on simulator - everything looks good.

The problem is that app is stucking on loading indicator. It doesnt't even respond to break points in ExtensionDelegate or InterfaceControllers.

I tried to set another InterfaceController as initial - it didnt't help.
It doesn't matter which iPhone is paired with Watch.

I made new clean "Hello world" app. After first run the problem happened again.

I think the problem might be associated with error like "could not attach to pid XXX". 
When I try to run app after the PID error it doesn't appear again and XCode shows the information that "Running xxx on Apple Watch (iPhone)" in the top bar.

The problem appears on other macs.
We work on OS X Sierra, XCode 8.2.1, iOS 9-10, Watch OS 3.1.3.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, I solve it. The only thing i had to do was to turn off and on the watch...

Answer (score 0):

Try build the app on actual iPhone first, see if it works. Then pair with Apple Watch after that.

Once paired, you'll need to edit the build scheme (right of stop button) to include Apple Watch build and target.

Hope it helps